# Script to randomly generate pictures and text from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm essentially trying to set it up so that when I click a button on my site, the page refreshes with either a random piece of text from an array and a random image from an array. I've got the text part down, but need to know how to do the picture part. This is the script I'm using right now for the text generator:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "You'll want to track-change your life";
r_text[1] = "A misplaced comma can get you fired";
r_text[2] = "Work-life balance? Ha!";
r_text[3] = "Even the bankers laugh at you";
r_text[4] = "There's a gym so you can't leave the building";
r_text[5] = "Student debt can't be discharged";
r_text[6] = "Sallie Mae becomes one of your biggest contacts";
r_text[7] = "Good luck with partner track";
r_text[8] = "There are no lifestyle firms";
r_text[9] = "Your soul will die";
r_text[10] = "Socratic Method? More like Suck-ratic Method";
r_text[11] = "So much paper. You'll be destroying rainforests";
var i = Math.floor(12*Math.random())
document.write(r_text[i]);
</script>
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get images in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put img tags in the same array, so it mixes with text:

```
....
r_text[12] = "<img src='1.gif' />";
r_text[13] = "<img src='2.gif' />";
...
```

etc....

Comment: I think this works. the gif needs to be in the same folder as the main html file, right?

Comment: your `src=''` is specifying where to look for imgs, i.e.: `src='images/1.gif'` - means folder `images` is on the same level as the page displaying them

Answer (score 1):

```
var r_images = new Array (); 
r_images[0] = "a.jpg";
r_images[1] = "b.jpg;
.
.
.


var i = Math.floor(12*Math.random())
document.write(r_text[i]);
document.write("<img src='"+images_folder+r_images[i]+"' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the same thing for an image?

```
var imageNames = ['life', 'fired', 'balance', 'bakers', 'gym']
var i = Math.floor(5*Math.random())
document.write("<img src='http://path/to/your/image/" + imageNames[i] + ".jpg'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

set a folder for images and give them random name onward 12,13,14 .......than same like text

```
var i = Math.floor(24*Math.random())
document.write("<img src='folder-path/" + r_text[i] + ".jpg'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but for future readers, consider using `innerHTML` in lieu of `document.write` and also I recommend changing `var i = Math.floor(12*Math.random())` to `var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());` that way as you add more images you don't have to worry about changing the number next to `*Math.random())`

In this example I've used Array objects so that you can easily define the alt text (for those validation sticklers) for each image.

For anyone that cares for a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmZPe/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var r_img = [];
r_img[0] = {
    source:
        "image01.png",
    altText:
        "image 01"
};
r_img[1] = {
    source:
        "image02.png",
    altText:
        "image 02"
};
r_img[2] = {
    source:
        "image03.png",
    altText:
        "image 03"
};

var i = Math.floor(r_img.length * Math.random());
var s = "<img src='http://tinyurl.com/ky3nmqp/" + r_img[i].source + "' alt='" + r_img[i].altText + "'>";
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = s;
```

---

Or if you prefer, we can wrap it in a function call it when an event occurs:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmZPe/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var r_img = [];
    r_img[0] = {
        source:
            "image01.png",
        altText:
            "image 01"
    };
    r_img[1] = {
        source:
            "image02.png",
        altText:
            "image 02"
    };
    r_img[2] = {
        source:
            "image03.png",
        altText:
            "image 03"
    };

    var i = Math.floor(r_img.length * Math.random());
    var s = "<img src='http://tinyurl.com/ky3nmqp/" + r_img[i].source + "' alt='" + r_img[i].altText + "'>";
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = s;
}
```